# Find the determinant of addition of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x, y \in \mathrm{R^n}$. Show that det$(I - xy^T) = 1 - y^{T}x$.

I test several cases for this problem, and it holds true when $n = 2, 3$, but when it comes to proof, I tried two ways and both failed:

- Write $x, y$ explicitly in the form of $a_{ij}, b_{ij}$, and tried to find the relationship between the left and right side. But the left side could not be reduced to a relatively clearer form and turns out to add more complexity.
- Try to transform $I - xy^T$ into something similar to the right side.

I think the difficulty of this problem lies in the transformation from matrix $(I - xy^T)$ into scalar $1 - y^{T}x$, and I do not have a good way to make such transformation.

This question could be answered with matrix determinant lemma (the proof could be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). Even though this is pretty easy to understand, it lacks the reasoning process, which I find very unsatisfying.

Comment: Classical question (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

Comment: Even though this is pretty easy to understand. But I could not find the reasoning process in this page. Why they will create these structures?

Comment: The creation of these structures is rather natural when you write your matrix under the form $I_n-u^TI_n^{-1}v$ and recognize in it a **Schur complement** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), a very classical tool in the framework of "matrix-by-blocks computation".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x\neq0$. Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix such that $A\frac{x}{|x|}=e_1$, where $e_1=(1,0,\cdots,0)^T$ and then $Ax=|x|e_1$. Let $Ay=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)^T$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\det(I-xy^T)&=&\det[A(I-xy^T)A^T]\\
&=&\det[I-(Ax)(Ay)^T]\\
&=&\det(I-|x|e_1(Ay)^T]\\
&=&1-|x|y_1.
\end{eqnarray}
Noting
$$ |x|y_1=|x|e_1(Ay)^T=|x|(e_1,Ay)=(Ax,Ay)=(x,y)=x^Ty$$
one has
$$ \det(I-xy^T)=1-x^Ty. $$

Comment: This proof is pretty smart even though it is not quite straightforward and I think it is much better than what matrix determinant lemma say. But I am wondering why $Ax$ could be written as $\vert x \vert e_{1}$

Comment: @Mr.Robot, this is because an orthogonal matrix transforms a unit vector to a unite vector.